# Merge PCollections in Google Dataflow

Tags: merge, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am new to Google Dataflow and am working with catalogdata where I want to join catalogs of different languages. For now, my process parses both the languages for themselves, and creates a PCollection for each language. This PCollection contains one element, that contains Metadata, all Articles and all Categories. The Model is ready to hold multiple languages and all I need to do now, is to merge those 2 Elements (PCollections).

But.... The Google Dataflow Documentation doesn't provide examples on how to merge those collections "by hand" and the Inputs on apply always need a specific Input-Type. 
I tried the PCollectionList but cannot find a solution where I can work with all containing PCollections and their entities. Then I wrote a Custom CombineFn but I don't know how to apply it, so that both Collections get combined.

So I have the 2 PCollection catalogCollection_de and catalogCollection_fr. How can I process these to customly join them and get a single PCollection?

Any help is highly appreciated

EDIT: to the question what "merge/join" means in this context.
The PCollections Object holds a Pojo called CatalogCollection, which contains Metadata, Categories and Articles. Each of those Pojos has different texts, where each text is represented by a `Map<LanguageKey, Description>`. For each language, there is a PCollection holding this CatalogCollection. When I want to join/merge them, I want to collect all the languages in one PCollection, meaning that, for example, for each Article, I need to find the corresponding Article in the other language, and put all the descriptions to the first Collection, where in the end, all languages should be collected.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what merging actually does here? In general, having a PCollection of a single element isn't going to be paralellizable. You would likely be better off having a PCollection of articles, a PCollection of categories, etc. Each article could be keyed by the language it was part of, etc.

Comment: +1 to what Ben said, and in that case you will need the CoGroupByKey transform to join the collections by key. (Perhaps join is what you meant by merge?)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Dataflow parallelizes execution over the elements in a PCollection. If you have a PCollection with a single object, it will not be executed in parallel, and won't give you much benefit. Instead of having a single object, you would be better having a `PCollection<KV<LanguageKey, Description>>` etc. Now there are many elements. To align articles, you would want to run a `DoFn` that creates `PCollection<KV<ArticleId, Article>>` then you could run a `GroupByKey` or `CoGroupByKey` to match up the articles.

Comment: As I am in an experimenting phase, I managed to "merge" my PCollections with a Custom DoFn with sideInput, where I have access to both POJOs. Now my Custom "merge" works. In the next Iteration, I will try to work with PCollections of Articles/Categories etc. where the parallelization of Dataflow can do it's magic. Main factor for Dataflow was the fast "read and write" to Google Datastore. Thank you very much for your Input @Ben Chambers! When I do the next Iteration, maybe I will come back to that Thread and update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my Usecase, it seems like the way to go was using a ParDo with sideinput and join the PoJos manually (due to my datastructure). Also with an updated Pipeline, where the PCollections are broken down to Articles / Categories etc. I had to custom merge them. 
Problem now is, that the reads from Datastore won't work, but thats in another thread.

Answer (score 4):

The transform you are look for is [Flatten](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Flatten):

```
PCollection<String> pc1 = ...;
PCollection<String> pc2 = ...;
PCollection<String> pc3 = ...;
PCollectionList<String> pcs = PCollectionList.of(pc1).and(pc2).and(pc3);
PCollection<String> merged = pcs.apply(Flatten.<String>pCollections());
```

Also note: I noticed you said "this collection contains one element" which suggests you may also run into problems since Dataflow distributes elements across workers for parallel processing. With only element, you may not get the parallelism benefits you would expect.

Comment: But it doesnt seem like I could customize the flatten operation. How would dataflow know what to do?

Comment: after parsing the result to a Json-String, it seems like it just concatenated the two Collections. i need to merge them

Comment: What does "merge" mean here?